# SQL SSIS OleDB Command destination errors handling

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledbcommand

In an SSIS package, I want to execute a stored procedure for multiple rows defined by a Select. I use for this an OLE DB Command in destination with the parameter mapping.
However, I have errors. I did configure the error output to redirect the rows to an SQL table and it works fine. My problem is that the returned error is not at all self-explanatory. I just get error code 1073704166. Is there a way to get a more explicit error message?

I clarify that by using the same data for a given row, the stored procedure works fine when run from SSMS.

Thank you

Comment: This is a generic error raised by SSIS to say that the command generated errors.  It might be fussy with the syntax, could you add the command and double check that the datatypes from the columns match the datatypes for the parameters in the proc?

Comment: How are you executing the package?

Comment: @Larnu Only the data flow for testing

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz Checked again. DataTypes matches

Comment: Not *what* are you executing, now are you, @MosheHAYUN . Is this deployed via SSISDB, MSDB? Are you using Agent, T-SQL? Etc.

Comment: @Larnu, sorry :)

On Visual studio for now. Manually

Comment: Ok, now I used the KingswaySoft Premium Ado.Net destination component, and the error is more explicit. I solved it. 

Thanks